# Referring to an older adult as "grandpa"

Tags: word-usage

I'm aware that calling an older adult "grandpa" is extremely rude , but if I had a friendly neighbor in their 80's who I really enjoy being around , would it be okay if I referred to them as "grandpa" like saying for example : 
"we have this very nice grandpa who lives next door"
or it would be better to say "a grandfatherly neighbor" ?

Answer (score 2):

I think **uncle** is a better choice than **grandpa**, because

- he is only one generation away, not two, implying less age
- it is more commonly used in such circumstances

This is backed up by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/uncle)

> **uncle**
>   NOUN
>
> **1.1** *informal* An unrelated older male friend, especially of a child.
>   *He is more like your friendly neighbourhood uncle with a passion for sports.*

The Lexico entry for [**grandpa**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grandpa) shows no such usage.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context, but the likely answer is "No". As you know "calling an older adult "grandpa" is extremely rude".  Well, perhaps not *extremely*, but is shows an inappropriate attitude. As you already know this, I wonder why you think it might be okay to be rude to an old man who lives next door and you enjoy being around.

If you are a young child it might be acceptable. If the old man has told you that you can call him "grandpa" then it should be okay. But adults don't usually refer to old men as "grandpa" (unless they are talking about their own grandpa).

Similarly, it is possible that a close family friend might be called "uncle" by the children in the house.  But the adults would not use "uncle" (except when talking to the children).

It is unlikely that an English language learner will be in a situation in which it would be appropriate to refer to an unrelated older man as "grandpa".  The usual polite way to refer to an unrelated person is by their name.  "Joe" or "William" or whatever.

I would not say a "grandfatherly neighbour".  Instead, I'd say a "friendly neighbour".

Comment: Thank you for your replay.....I'd like to make something clear though , I do believe that it's inappropriate to call an older person "grandpa" , but I was wondering if I could refer to them as so since there's no ill intention involved...you said : "If the old man has told you that you can call him "grandpa" then it should be okay" , so the context here is what made it okay to call him "grandpa" , all I was interested in knowing was whether or not there was such a context . thank you again for the clarification :)